# Disappearing <textarea> after $.slideDown()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue in IE7 and below where a form that I'm toggling the display of via `$.slideUp()` & `$.slideDown()`, has an disappearing textarea.

This is the form code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addCommentForm", @class = "comments-form" }))
 { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="SiteID" value="<%: Model.Name %>" />
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col class="comments-form-text" />
            <col class="comments-form-submit" />
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="Text" rows="2" cols="75"></textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <% } %>
```

I'm toggling the display on a button click in javascript (using jQuery) with:             `$('#addCommentForm').slideDown();`

My issue is that in IE7 and below, the text area disappears when the form has finished sliding down. It only reappears when I most over the submit button (which has been styled using jQueryUI `.button()` method).

When I say disappears, it's gone. Looking at the html in the IE Dev Tools, it's html is still there, it's just not being rendered at all.

As much as I absolutely hate IE, I am required to support it :(

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Or how I can mitigate it?

Comment: What happens if you use .show() instead of slidedown?

Comment: @krio: `.show()` works as expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are some ways of solving this problem:

- Try using another element, like a
  `span` instead of a `div` element to
  slideDown. Might be an IE's rendering
  bug;
- Another approach, is to set `zoom:1;`
  in your CSS to the element you're
  trying to slideDown;
- You can also solve this setting a
  `min-height` to your sliding element in
  your CSS;

Comment: Applying zoom to the element worked for me as well. eg: $('.element').slideDown('slow').css('zoom', 1); @Ron - It probably has something to do with forcing the element to have the "hasLayout" property.

Comment: Confirmed, had the exact same issue in IE7, the $('.element').slideDown('slow').css('zoom', 1); solution worked like a charm. Thank you guys for saving me valuable time!

Comment: I ended up refactoring my HTML to not need the slide-down, but as this seems to be fixing issue for other people, accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting a width on the element will solve the problem. All of @paulillo solutions work well but setting the width will help protect you from other related bugs.

slideDown temporarily sets the position to absolute, which sometimes produces a bug known as the "jump" bug. This happens because sometimes slideDown can't accurately calculate the height when the element width is altered in the brief moment its absolute. I hate setting width unless I have to but in this case, if you can, I would recommend it.

Comment: I just ran into this issue for an application supporting ie7 and choose this method based on your good explanation.  Works well, thanks.